# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI'

Tags: json, swift, decode

I m using this code to call my rest web service.
But if I try to decode the result of web service call I received error.

```
class func callPostServiceReturnJson(apiUrl urlString: String, parameters params : [String: AnyObject]?,  parentViewController parentVC: UIViewController, successBlock success : @escaping ( _ responseData : AnyObject, _  message: String) -> Void, failureBlock failure: @escaping (_ error: Error) -> Void) {
        
        if Utility.checkNetworkConnectivityWithDisplayAlert(isShowAlert: true) {
            var strMainUrl:String! = urlString + "?"

            for dicd in params! {
                strMainUrl.append("\(dicd.key)=\(dicd.value)&")
            }
            print("Print Rest API : \(strMainUrl ?? "")")


            let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
            manager.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: params)
                .responseJSON {
                    response in
                    switch (response.result) {
                    case .success:
                        do{
                                            
                                        
                            let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(OrderStore.self, from: response.result.value! as! Data)
                            
                        }catch{
                            print("errore durante la decodifica dei dati: \(error)")
                        }
                        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                            success(response as AnyObject, "Successfull")
                        }
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                        if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                            //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            failure(error)
                        } else {
                            print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                            failure(error)
                        }
                        break
                    }
            }
        } else {
            parentVC.hideProgressBar();
            Utility.showAlertMessage(withTitle: EMPTY_STRING, message: NETWORK_ERROR_MSG, delegate: nil, parentViewController: parentVC)
        }
    }
```

This is the error that I can print:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff86d70b80) to 'NSData' (0x7fff86d711e8).
2021-09-27 16:34:49.810245+0200 ArrivaArrivaStore[15017:380373] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff86d70b80) to 'NSData' (0x7fff86d711e8).
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff86d70b80) to 'NSData' (0x7fff86d711e8).
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 8 (6F09ED5B-8607-4E47-8E2E-A89243B9BA90) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
```

I generated OrderStore.swift class from https://app.quicktype.io/

//EDIT
[image]

Comment: Well, do you understand the error?

Comment: yes but I don't know how can I fixed it

Comment: It means that `response.result.value` is a `Dictionary`, not a `Data`, if that's really the line causing the crash (giving it would help). You use `responseJSON{}`, so `response.result.value` is a Dictionary or an Array since `JSONSerialization` has been called already on it. Use `response.result.data` if I remember correctly. If it works, then use the Alamofire method that allow to decode directly into your Codable struct (avoiding an uncessary already call to JSONSeriallization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.responseJSON` returns deserialized JSON, in this case a `Dictionary`. It cannot be cast to `Data` what the error clearly confirms.

To get the raw data you have to specify `.responseData`

Replace

```
.responseJSON {
      response in
         switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                    do {
                       let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(OrderStore.self, from: response.result.value! as! Data)
```

with

```
.responseData {
      response in
         switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                    do {
                       let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(OrderStore.self, from: data)
```

Consider that AF 5 supports even `.responseDecodable` to decode directly into the model

```
.responseDecodable {
      (response : DataResponse<OrderStore,AFError>) in
         switch response.result {
            case .success(let users): print(users)
```

Side notes:

- As mentioned in your previous question there is no `AnyObject` in the AF API. The parameters are `[String:Any]` and `responseData` is the decoded type. I recommend to make the function generic and use the convenient `Result` type.
- Delete the `break` statements. This is Swift.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the error is the same. I add in my question the type of (let data)

Comment: If you replace the code exactly as suggested the *same error* cannot occur.

Comment: I m using your code .respondeData but this is the error now:

errore durante la decodifica dei dati: typeMismatch(ArrivaArrivaStore.JSONNull, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "time_booking", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: That's a different error, a DecodingError. It says that in the second item of the array `result` the type of the property `time_booking` is wrong.

Comment: time_booking is not mandatory, the jason can contain this field and cannot contain this.
In My OrderStore.swift class Is declared like this: let timeBooking: JSONNull?

Comment: Instead of `JSONNull?` declare it as the optional real type.

Comment: are you the best

Answer (score 0):

*This is an addendum to Vadian's answer. I'm trying to illustrate the process that lead you into this error, with the hopes that you can notice it in the future, before it leads you astray*

This is a pretty common "pattern" of error.

Picture it as though you're traversing a maze, starting from some initial data format, and trying to get to some destination data format. At each point along the way, there are several options to choose from, some which get you closer to your goal, and some which lead you further away.

You've chosen to enter the maze at the entryway called [`responseJSON`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/DownloadRequest.html#/s:9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC12responseJSON5queue16dataPreprocessor18emptyResponseCodes0iC7Methods7options17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_F0C_AA04DataH0_pShySiGShyAA10HTTPMethodVGSo20NSJSONReadingOptionsVyAA0bJ0VyypAA7AFErrorOGctF), whose callback will give you a `AFDownloadResponse<Any>` (which is the inferred type of the variable you called `response`).

JSON structures always have an array or dictionary at the top level. Since Alamofire can't statically know which kind of JSON you'll be dealing with, it models this with an `Any`. At runtime, the type of the `Value` will be either `NSDictionary` (or one of its concrete subclasses, like `__NSDictionaryI`) or `NSArray` (or one of its concrete subclasses).

You then decide to get the `result` of that `response`. Its static type is  `Result<Any, Error>`. You `switch` over this error, ensuring you're dealing with the `success` case and not the `failure` case. Inexplicably, you ignore the payload value associated with the success, but later force unwrap it out with `result.response.value!`.

`result.response.value` is an `Any`, but to placate the compiler your force-cast it to a `Data`. But we already know this will only ever be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, so this will *never* work.

You could keep wandering around in this area of the maze, and stumble to the end goal via a long path. For example, you could force cast to `NSDictionary`, then re-serialize that dictionary structure back to a JSON string, which you can turn into `Data`, only for you to then pass it to `JSONDecoder().decode`, which will then decode that JSON back. Of course, this is all awfully round-about and wasteful. The issue was the that `responseJSON` maze entrance was not the right one for where you're trying to go!

You could have instead entered into the [`responseData`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/DownloadRequest.html#/s:9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC12responseData5queue16dataPreprocessor18emptyResponseCodes0iC7Methods17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_F0C_AA0eH0_pShySiGShyAA10HTTPMethodVGyAA0bJ0Vy10Foundation0E0VAA7AFErrorOGctF) maze entrance, which gets you right to your `Data` destination!

Though you might then realize that the `Data` was a red herring all along. You didn't actually want `Data`. You wanted to decode an `OrderStore`, and `Data` was how you thought you needed to get there. But it turns out that so many people were entering through the `Data` entrance with the intent to decode some JSON, that the Alamofire people carved out a new entrance just for you: [`responseDecodable`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/DownloadRequest.html#/s:9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC17responseDecodable2of5queue16dataPreprocessor7decoder18emptyResponseCodes0kC7Methods17completionHandlerACXDxm_So012OS_dispatch_G0CAA04DataI0_pAA0S7Decoder_pShySiGShyAA10HTTPMethodVGyAA0bL0VyxAA7AFErrorOGctSeRzlF). It takes you *right* to the `OrderStore`, and fiddles around with the JSON, `Data` or whatever, under the hood where you don't have to worry about it.